# koala: how to get shares from Facebook Graph API

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

I'm trying to get the count of shares from a Facebook page, but I can't seem to get the result out of the hash.
Here's what I have:

```
y_response = @graph.get_connection('some_fb_page','posts',
                            {fields: ['message', 'id', 'from', 'type', 
'properties', 'link', 'shares', 'likes.summary(true)', 
 'comments.summary(true)', 'created_time', 'updated_time']
                            })
```

So y_response is Koala::Facebook::API::GraphCollection

```
y_response.each do |post|
```

and each of the post elements is a Hash

```
puts post["shares"]
```

gives me: {"count"=>3}

but

```
puts post["shares"]["count"]
```

gives an

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I've also tried

```
puts post["shares"][:count]
puts post["shares"][count]
puts post["shares"].count
```

for laughs.

What am I doing wrong?
How do I get the count from the hash?

Comment: What `post.inspect` and `post.class` returns?